# Why does Hadoop plugin for eclipse ignore changes I make to the program?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I have recently setup a vmware instance with hadoop on my windows 7 machine. I also setup hadoop plugin within eclipse and successfully ran an example map-reduce program on the VM. However the changes I make to the mapreduce program in Eclipse doesn't get reflected in the run. When I run it through eclipse, it still runs the initial program. I tried setting up a new map reduce program from scratch using my changed code and I was able to run it with my changes. However any change I make after the first run doesn't take effect. If the code has compile errors Eclipse complains and it doesnt run but when it runs it still runs the first version. 
I am using hadoop 0.18.0, vmware image from yahoo's tutorial and eclipse 3.3.2. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Does this problem happen only with the Hadoop plugin? I am not sure what people get from the plugin. Why not just use Hadoop as an external archive in eclipse, and run things as usual, like with any other java program. That is my set up. What does one get from the plugin?

Comment: I think with plugin it was supposed to be easier for noobs like me to get started without too much configuration headaches. Also it is easy to copy files to and from DFS in the hadoop instance and view the results without going into the VM. I'll probably ditch the plugin if I cannot figure this out.

Comment: If you are debugging or running on local only, for dev and test purposes, it is really very easy to set up the config. In fact, eclipse might me ignoring the config file all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody falls into the same trap here's how I resolved this problem.

The solution to this problem is to choose "Run--> Run As-->Run on Hadoop". This is what creates a .jar file (and site.conf file) that gets passed to Hadoop instance. After the .jar file is created it is copied to a folder that is listed in the "Run/Debug settings-->classpath" of the project. This is what Hadoop executes.

If you run your map reduce program as a regular java application (e.g. using the run short cut keys) like I was doing; it still runs the hadoop program but the .jar file for Hadoop does not get recreated. This results in same program being run again and again.

[image: Run as options]
[image: Classpath in run/debug properties in project properties]